# Modificando item de uma lista compartilhada por várias threads

Tags: c#, task

Tenho o seguinte pseudo-código:

```
public void Associar(List<Data> dados)
{
   List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
   foreach(dado in dados)
   {
       tasks.Add(AdicionarAsync(dado));
   }
   Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

   Debug.WriteLine(dados.Select(e => e.Colecao).Sum(e => e.Count));
}

public async Task AdicionarAsync(Data dado)
{
   dado.Colecao = await consultanobanco(dado.Id);
}
```

O output deste código deveria ser sempre 411 (equivalente a soma dos registros na base de dados). Contudo, o resultado varia sempre que o método Associar é executado. Coloquei um `Thread.Sleep(10);` apenas para verificar se seria problema de concorrência e o problema foi *"solucionado"*. Qual é a forma correta de utilizar uma lista `thread safe` para modificar cada item de uma coleção distribuído em várias Tasks?

Debugando o código um pouco mais, notei que a diferença de valores está na verdade na linha `dado.Colecao = await consultanobanco();`

Dentro do método `consultanobanco();` o retorno está correto. Contudo, ao chegar na atribuição para `dado.Colecao` ele chega errado. Modificando de `await consultanobanco();` para `consultanobanco().Result` o resultado é retornado conforme o esperado.

Alguma razão para este comportamento? Qual a diferença entre await e .Result neste cenário?

Comment: ja tentou await AdicionarAsync?

Answer (score 1):

Bem o problema ocorre porque você está a mudar o estado do objeto numa thread diferente daquela que o lê. Mais precisamente essa linha está a dar problemas, como você constatou:

```
dado.Colecao = await consultanobanco();
```

Eu não sei ao certo porque o `.Result` dá certo, o melhor mesmo é não fiar muito nisso. A framework .Net é livre de dicidir se deve de usar ou não uma thread do thread pool para executar o trabalho duma task, talvez nesse caso não use.

Eu não vou dizer qual é a solução para este problema pois acredito que tenha um problema maior antes deste. Repare que a propriedade Colecao de todos os objetos da lista de dados terão os mesmos dados, a não ser que o comportamento de `consultanobanco` não seja deterministico. Na verdade até pode acontecer ter uma condição de corrida, em que os dados da base de dados mudam e apenas alguns dos objetos da lista têm essa mudança.

O melhor mesmo é ler os dados uma vez e partilha-los por todos os objetos. Por razões de eficiência também.

```
public asyn Task Associar(List<Data> dados)
{
   var dadosDoBanco = await consultanobanco();
   foreach(dado in dados)
   {
       dado.Colecao = dadosDoBanco;
   }

   Debug.WriteLine(dados.Select(e => e.Colecao).Sum(e => e.Count));
}
```

Comment: o pseudometodo consultanobanco depende de dados especificos para retornar seus valores, atualizei a pergunta com um exemplo. Ele é feito em paralelo porque as consultas demoram muito (cerca de minutos), e seria muito demorado para ser feito sincronamente.

Comment: @JoãoPaulo Em vez de fazer carregamento lazy, faca carregamento eager. Ou seja, quando voce obtem o seu objeto Data da base de dados ele deve já vir com a informacao da colecao. Uma outra alternativa é carregar todos os objetos de uma só vez, em vez de fazer uma consulta para cada objeto.

Comment: Esta consulta está sendo realizada por uma razão, não pode vir diretamente com o objeto na consulta ao banco de dados. E como disse, são milhões (bilhões em certas circunstâncias), então não é possível colocar todos em memória. A paralelização destas consultas foi uma solução que se encaixou no caso, mas está com esta "característica" que não consigo encontrar o motivo... utilizando o .Result hoje está sendo executado normalmente

Comment: @JoãoPaulo Parece estar a escapar qualquer coisa. Eu nunca disse para trazer os dados todos. Eu apenas disse para trazer todos **os que necessita** de uma só vez. Se mesmo assim eles são milhões como você diz, se calhar precisa de fazer paginação.

Comment: Estou falando dos dados que são necessários mesmo. Todavia, utilizando paginação eu teria de toda forma que paralelizar estas consultas, pois elam seriam muito demoradas igual

Comment: @JoãoPaulo Nao é bem assim. O que está tentando fazer no seu programa? Pelo jeito parece ser um migrador de dados/exportador/backup... ou um gestor de armazéns imenso xD

Comment: É exatamente isso, um exportador de dados em tempo real. =D

Comment: @JoãoPaulo parece que acertei. Aconselho-o a editar a sua pergunta. Voce precisa de colocar todos os detalhes. Qual é a sua base de dados? Pode utilizar uma ferramenta de migração para fazer a sua tarefa? Pode apenas fazer um script e correr no rdbms? Pode colocar o seu código real em vez de pseudo código? Pode simplesmente copiar o ficheiro da base de dados e dar-lhe outro nome? Coloque estas perguntas a voce mesmo porque ajuda a entender a sua necessidade e a melhor forma de resolver.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com essa [duvida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684320/starting-tasks-in-foreach-loop-uses-value-of-last-item) o seu problema pode está relacionado com [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) do foreach:

Tenta utilizar esse código para ver se o problema é corrigido:

```
public void Associar(List dados)
{
   List tasks = new List();
   foreach(dado in dados)
   {
       var tempDado = dado;
       tasks.Add(AdicionarAsync(tempDado));
   }
   Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

   Debug.WriteLine(dados.Select(e => e.Colecao).Sum(e => e.Count));
}

public async Task AdicionarAsync(Data dado)
{
   dado.Colecao = await consultanobanco(dado.Id);
}
```

Comment: Testei mas o resultado foi o mesmo